# How can I insert and rotate a 3D image in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, youtube, 3d

I am trying to insert a 3D image into xcode and I am having trouble as I have no idea on how to do it. I also want the image in rotate like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OvTCwwv5dY

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: And what is preventing you from putting in a best effort and then coming back to us with some specific problems?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where to start! @YannickMeeus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video you're referring to does not actually show a 3D image (all images are two dimensional by definition). It's a custom modal presentation, very similar to the iOS built-in modal presentation between two view controllers, using a transition type of "flip horizontal".

The thickness between view controllers is non-standard, and probably needs to be implemented as a custom segue.

If you can live without the thickness, you can create the standard iOS flip without any code in Interface Builder:

- start with a single view application
- create a second view controller in your storyboard
- create a button on the first view controller
- control drag from the first button to the second view controller
- select the segue you've just created
- in the Attributes Inspector, set the transition type to "flip horizontal" and the presentation style to "present modally"

[image]

All you need to do now is implement a dismissal method in your second view controller to transition back.

Comment: thanks alot for your help and advice, it has help me alot!